# Continuous differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, linear-transformations

I have a question about continuous differentiability of functions. Suppose we have a function $f$ which is differentiable, if we regard derivatives as functions, by definition

> $f'$ is continuous if for for all $x_{0}$, all $\epsilon >0$, we can find $\delta >0$ such that $|f'(x)-f'(x_{0})|< \epsilon$ when $|x-x_{0}|<\delta$

But if we regard derivatives as linear operator, the definition of continuity becomes

> $f$ is continuously differentiable if for all $\epsilon >0$, we can find $\delta>0$ such that $||f'(y)-f'(x)||< \epsilon$ when $|x-y|<\delta$
>
> If $A$ is a linear operator $A \in L(\Bbb R^{n},\Bbb R^{m})$, the norm $||A||$ is the sup of all numbers $|Ax|$, where $x$ ranges over all vectors in $\Bbb R^{n}$ with $|x|<1$

My question is that, are these two definitions equivalent? If they are, how to prove it?

Comment: First comment: You've written the definition of *uniform continuity*, not of continuity.

Comment: One thing is the differential, which is a function of both the point in question and the increment. As a function of the increment it is linear and always continuous. As a function of the point it is not necessarily linear. Continuous differentiability refers to the continuity of the partial derivatives, or as some people call derivative to the matrix of the differential in some coordinates, to the continuity of this matrix as a function of the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The two conditions are not equivalent.**

For example, pick $f(x)=x^3$. Then $f'$ satisfies the first condition but not the second.

**Note** If you consider the derivative $Df({\bf x}) = \left[\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}({\bf x})\right]$ as an operator, your second definition is the definition of $Df(x): \mathbb R^m \to \mathcal{M}_{m,n}(\mathbb R)$ being uniformly continuous, not continuous.

Comment: if I change the first definition to be uniform continuity, are they equivalent then?

Comment: @Vector Yes.You have to be carefull though with what you mean by $|f'(x)-f'(x_0)|$ in the first line, since $f$ is a multivariable function; this should be a norm. But since all norms are equivalent on finite dimensional space the two definitions will be equivalent.